# python find duplicate objects in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have a list

```
l = [object0, object1, object2, object3, object4....object499]
```

maximum length is never more than 500

All objects have attribute x, y, z, a

I have to modify object.y if duplicates in object.x as:

```
if object9.x == object10.x:
  object9.y = object9.z * object9.a/1000
  object10.y = object10.y - object9.z * object9.a/1000
```

It is guaranteed that duplicates will be in consecutive objects.

There may be more than 2 duplicates ie for example

```
object12.x == object13.x == object14.x
```

so modification will proceed in the same manner of the third duplicate based on the value of modified 2nd duplicate.

I have written a loop to do it, but was thinking if there is any pythonic/faster way of doing it.
I am using python3.7

EDIT:

```
tag = None
for i, o in enumerate(l):
  if tag is None:
     x_a = o.x
  elif x_a == o.x #duplicate found
    temp = o.y
    c_over = 0
    c_value = o[i-1].z * o[i-1].a/1000
    if c_value < o[i-1].y:
       o[i-1].y = c_value
       c_over = temp - c_value #carry over value
    o[i] = c_over # either zero of carry over value
  x_a = o.x
```

Comment: Could you show your existing loop so others may be able to suggest how to improve it, or otherwise suggest alternative methods?

Comment: You want `itertools.groupby`, with `operator.attrgetter('x')` as the `key` function.

Comment: You can iterate on couples of your list with `for (prev, current) in zip(l, l[1:]):`

Comment: Right now enumerating on list and if duplicate found then modify the previous element.
posting the code of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're modifying attributes of your objects you can loop over consecutive pairs via `zip`:

```
for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]):
    if a.x == b.x:
        a.y = a.z * a.a/1000
        b.y = b.y - a.y
```

Comment: what makes it a bit more tricky than that is that there might be a `c` for which `b.x == c.x` but since you are modifying `b` before checking `c` you are missing it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `b.x` is never modified so nothing is missed here. `x` is used for the check and `y` gets modified.

Comment: You are right. There is a bit of ambiguity there in the question come to think of it a bit harder. It is not clear to me if the modification takes place from the beginning or the end of the group. Assuming a triplet of (a, b, c), the modification of `c` will take place with the already modified value of `b` in both your and my answer.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That's explicitly required by the OP: *"[...] so modification will proceed in the same manner of the third duplicate based on the value of modified 2nd duplicate."*

Answer (score 3):

[@Shadow Ranger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668580/python-find-duplicate-objects-in-a-list#comment107337100_60668580) is definitely the way to go here. I did not test this any but it should do the trick

```
import itertools
import operator


l = [object0, object1, object2, object3, object4]

for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, key=operator.attrgetter('x')):
    l = list(g)
    for o1, o2, in zip(l, l[1:]):  # Note 1, 2
        o1.y = o1.z * o1.a / 1000
        o2.y = o2.z - o1.y
```

Notes:

1. assuming you modify the groups from beginning to the end. If you want to do it the other way round, you have to replace `zip(l, l[1:])` with `zip(l[len(l)-2::-1], l[::-1])`
2. kudos @ShadowRanger for pointing out that the `if` check is not needed (handled by the `zip`)

Comment: Note: You don't need to check the length (the `zip` will just terminate immediately if `l[1:]` is empty), and if you're running forwards, you could use `itertools.tee`, to avoid `list`ifying at all (which makes it completely lazy; no realizing elements before you need them). `g, g2 = itertools.tee(g)`, `next(g2)`, `for o1, o2 in zip(g, g2):`